# YouTube reporting API reports are all blank

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have created set of YouTube reporting jobs for a YouTube channel. The jobs were created and run every day as scheduled. However when I go to download the jobs they are all blank.

This is how I authenticate with the API:

```
def authenticate_from_credentials(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION):
        youtube_client_id = os.environ['youtube_client_id']
        youtube_client_secret = os.environ['youtube_client_secret']
        youtube_refresh_token = os.environ['youtube_refresh_token']
        credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
            access_token=None,
            client_id=youtube_client_id,
            client_secret=youtube_client_secret,
            refresh_token=youtube_refresh_token,
            token_expiry=None,
            token_uri='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
            user_agent=None,
            revoke_uri=None
        )
        youtube_reporting = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
        return youtube_reporting
```

This is the method I have been using to create the jobs:

```
# Call the YouTube Reporting API's jobs.create method to create a job.
def create_reporting_job(youtube_reporting, report_type_id, name):
  # Provide keyword arguments that have values as request parameters.
    reporting_job = youtube_reporting.jobs().create(
        body=dict(
          reportTypeId=report_type_id,
          name=name
        ),
      ).execute()
    print ('Reporting job "%s" created for reporting type "%s" at "%s"'
           % (reporting_job['name'], reporting_job['reportTypeId'],
              reporting_job['createTime']))
```

I authenticate like this:

```
youtube_reporting=authenticate_from_credentials('youtubereporting','v1')
```

And I will create a job like this:

```
create_reporting_job(youtube_reporting,"channel_combined_a2","Channel Combined a2")
```

I am not sure what the problem is here. The channel does have content and subscribers so the reports shouldn't be empty. I think there could be an issue with credentials or perhaps the wrong channel is associated with the report since the developer's Google accounts are different than the content owners. But I checked the channels associated with the Oauth credentials I am using and it was the right channel.

Why might my reports be empty and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue, the problem is that you need to wait several hours for the report to become generated on the backend, at which point re-querying for reports will show results.

There is a subtle mention about this delay on https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports under Step 3:

> The API response to the jobs.create method contains a Job resource,
> which specifies the ID that uniquely identifies the job. **You can
> start retrieving the report within 48 hours of the time that the job
> is created**, and the first available report will be for the day that
> you scheduled the job.

This was quite confusing.